# history implementation for a parse object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to implement the history feature for a lifecycle of an object. Basically I have an object Enquiry which has a one to many relationship with history. Meaning Enquiry object has pointers to an array of History rows. When a creates this object in before save i do this

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Enquiry", function(request, response)
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var currentObject = request.object;

    if (!currentObject.id) {
            var historicalData = new Array();

            var history = new Parse.Object("History");
            var userName = currentUser.get("firstname") + " " + currentUser.get("lastname");
            history.set("user", userName);
            history.set("summary", "Enquiry created ");
            history.save();
            historicalData.push(history);

            currentObject.set("history", historicalData);
   } else {
            //code to fetch existing Enquiry and figure out what changed
            ...
            ...


            var historicalData = existingEnquiry.get("history");

            var history = new Parse.Object("History");
            history.set("user", userName);
            history.set("summary", summary);
            history.save();
            historicalData.push(history);
            currentObject.set("history", historicalData);
    }
}
```

Now i can see that history object gets created and assigned to the newly created object fine. Also when i update the object i can see another History object being persisted in the db but the problem is that Enquiry to History reference doesn't change, meaning the Enquiry object still points to the History object that was created when the Enquire was created.

What i do not understand is even though i have added the updated array to the Enquiry's history column why that column doesn't update. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save current object after "currentObject.set("history", historicalData)" statement.

i.e 
currentObject.save();

Comment: also please see that the method is beforeSave which means save would anyway be called after this.

Comment: Try adding response.success(); at the end. May be parse is not accepting the response and so not calling afterSave.